# Porque meu ajax só funciona quando quer?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tenho uma página que é mistura de HTML com php que quando clico no botão `submit`, o JavaScript é acionado, pega todas as informações e chama uma função que ativa um ajax pra chamar um arquivo php.

Parece muito simples, porém, ela simplesmente funciona só quando quer! Eu já não sei mais o que pensar ou fazer, simplesmente tem vezes que o ajax chama a classe, ela executa tudo certinho e retorna para a `request.done` para executar outra função, e outra vezes ele simplesmente retorna para a `request.fail` por nenhum motivo aparente.

Não sei se é relevante, mas algumas informações eu passo por session da página HTML para o arquivo php. E observei que nas vezes que funciona, as sessions não conseguem chegar a última página. Essa última página é chamada quando o ajax consegue executar e entra no `request.done`.

Código JavaScript para pegar as informações:

```
window.cartao = 0;
data= new Date();
ano = data.getFullYear();
mes = data.getMonth() + 1;
var form = document.getElementById('caixa');
var cardNum = document.getElementById('cardNumber');
var expMes = document.getElementById('selectExpData');
var expAno = document.getElementById('InputAno');

var verifCod = document.getElementById('verifCode');
var nameCard = document.getElementById('nomeBox');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    var resultado = verificaCampos(ano, mes, cardNum, expMes, expAno, verifCod, nameCard);
    if(resultado == false) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {

        transacaoCredito(cardNum.value, expAno.value, expMes.value, verifCod.value, nameCard.value, window.cartao, <?php echo "$totalReal";?>, <?php echo "$Amount" ?> );

    }

});
```

a função que contém o ajax

```
function transacaoCredito(cardNum, expAno, expMes, verifCod, nameCard, cartao, valorReal, amount) {
var request = $.ajax({
 type: "post",
 url: "_classes/creditoTransacao.php",
 data:
 {
 "cardNum":cardNum,
 "expAno":expAno,
 "expMes":expMes,
 "verifCod":verifCod,
 "nameCard":nameCard,
 "cartao":cartao,
 "valorReal":valorReal,
 "amount":amount
 }
 });

 request.done(function (result) {
     mudaPagina(result);
 });

 request.fail(function () {
    alert('Ocorreu um erro, por favor tente novamente mais tarde');
 });
}
```

E o arquivo php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$cardNum = $_POST['cardNum'];
$expAno = $_POST['expAno'];
$expMes = $_POST['expMes'];
$verifCod = $_POST['verifCod'];
$nameCard = $_POST['nameCard'];
$cartao = $_POST['cartao'];
$valorReal = $_POST['valorReal'];
$valorReal = number_format($valorReal, 2, "", "");
$valorReal = (integer) $valorReal;
$Amount = $_POST['amount'];
/*teste
$Amount = number_format($Amount, 2, "", "");
$Amount = (integer) $Amount;
//teste*/

$ourOrderId = $_SESSION['ourOrderId'];
$ourReturnUrl = $_SESSION['ourReturnUrl'];
$ourNotifyUrl = $_SESSION['ourNotifyUrl'];
$CurrencyCode = $_SESSION['CurrencyCode'];

/*$ourOrderId = $_POST['ourOrderId'];
$ourReturnUrl = $_POST['ourReturnUrl'];
$ourNotifyUrl = $_POST['ourNotifyUrl'];
$CurrencyCode = $_POST['CurrencyCode'];*/


require_once ('../vendor/autoload.php');
require_once ('../_classes/conexaoBanco.php');
use Cielo\Cielo;
use Cielo\CieloException;
use Cielo\Transaction;
use Cielo\Holder;
use Cielo\PaymentMethod;
use Cielo\Consultation;
$merchantId = '1111111111';
$merchantKey = '11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111';
$cielo = new Cielo($merchantId, $merchantKey, Cielo::TEST);
$holder = $cielo->holder($cardNum, $expAno, $expMes, Holder::CVV_INFORMED, $verifCod);
$order = $cielo->order($ourOrderId, $valorReal);//$valorReal
switch ($cartao) {
    case 'visa':
        $paymentMethod = $cielo->paymentMethod(PaymentMethod::VISA, PaymentMethod::CREDITO_A_VISTA);
        break;
    case 'master':
        $paymentMethod = $cielo->paymentMethod(PaymentMethod::MASTERCARD, PaymentMethod::CREDITO_A_VISTA);
        break;
    case 'discover':
        $paymentMethod = $cielo->paymentMethod(PaymentMethod::DISCOVER, PaymentMethod::CREDITO_A_VISTA);
        break;
    case 'amex':
        $paymentMethod = $cielo->paymentMethod(PaymentMethod::AMEX, PaymentMethod::CREDITO_A_VISTA);
        break;
    case 'diners':
        $paymentMethod = $cielo->paymentMethod(PaymentMethod::DINERS, PaymentMethod::CREDITO_A_VISTA);
        break;
    case 'jcb':
        $paymentMethod = $cielo->paymentMethod(PaymentMethod::JCB, PaymentMethod::CREDITO_A_VISTA);
        break;
    case 'elo':
        $paymentMethod = $cielo->paymentMethod(PaymentMethod::ELO, PaymentMethod::CREDITO_A_VISTA);
        break;
    case 'aura':
        $paymentMethod = $cielo->paymentMethod(PaymentMethod::AURA, PaymentMethod::CREDITO_A_VISTA);
        break;
}

$transaction = $cielo->transaction($holder, $order, $paymentMethod, $ourReturnUrl, Transaction::AUTHORIZE_WITHOUT_AUTHENTICATION, true);

try {
    $transaction = $cielo->transactionRequest($transaction);
    if ($transaction->getAuthorization()->getLr()==0){
        $tid = $transaction->getTid();
        $consultation = $cielo->consultation($tid);
        try {
            $consultationResponse = $cielo->consultationRequest($consultation);
            if (is_object($consultationResponse)) {
                $status = $consultationResponse->getStatus();

                switch ($status) {
                    case 0:
                        $statusBanco = "Transação criada com sucesso";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        $statusBanco = "Transação em Andamento";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $statusBanco = "Transação Autenticada";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $statusBanco = "Transação não Autenticada";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        $statusBanco = "Transação Autorizada";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        $statusBanco = "Transação não Autorizada";
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        $statusBanco = "Transação Capturada";
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        $statusBanco = "Transação Cancelada";
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        $statusBanco = "Transação em Autenticação";
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        $statusBanco = "Transação em Cancelamento";
                        break;
                    default:
                        $statusBanco = "Não há status da transação";
                }
                $mensagem = $consultationResponse->getAuthorization()->getMessage();
                $data = $consultationResponse->getAuthorization()->getDateTime();
                $data = new DateTime($data);
                $valorTotal = $consultationResponse->getAuthorization()->getTotal();
                $array = str_split($valorTotal);
                $antes = substr($valorTotal, 0
                    , count($array) - 2);
                $depois = substr($valorTotal, (count($array) - 2));
                $valorTotal = $antes . "." . $depois;

                $banco = new conexaoBanco();
                $banco->salvaBanco($tid,$cardNum,$nameCard,$valorTotal,$Amount,$statusBanco,$mensagem,$data->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $ourOrderId);

            }
        } catch (CieloException $ex) {
            echo "Erro[" . $ex->getCode() . "]: " . $ex->getMessage();
        }

        echo $status;

    } else {
        throw new CieloException($transaction->getAuthorization()->getLr());
    }
} catch(CieloException $ex) {
    echo "Erro[".$ex->getCode()."]: ".$ex->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Edit::
Pessoal, eu sei que não existe isso de "funciona quando quer", afinal eu também sou programador. O que eu quis dizer é que uma hora funciona e outra não. Achei que tinha ficado fácil de entender.

Comment: Seja Bem-Vindo ao SOpt, você já tentou usar o `Firebug` para ver o que está acontecendo?

Comment: Vou testar para averiguar, obrigado pela contribuição!

Comment: Cara, não existe esse negócio de ta funcionando quando quer.

Comment: Quando falha, no primeiro argumento do `request.fail` tem uma propriedade `responseText` o que tem lá?, ali tem o retorno do erro que aconteceu no PHP.

Comment: Tentei dar um alert no request.fail para exibir this.responseText e ele retornou undefined. Me ajude se tiver fazendo errado, por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa é boa funciona quando quer, se faz errado como vai funcionar.
Isso acontece por três motivos.

- Primeiro não sabem direito o conceito de ajax.
  (Conceito: Ajax é uma chamada assincrona que atualiza parte do DOM)
- Segundo motivo, uma chamada pode funcionar, hora sim, hora não, quando! A arvore do DOM esta desatualizada, então ela(função) tenta atualizar determinada parte e a instrução que atualiza, não sabe que aquela parte nem mesmo existe, **para evitar isso use tags container, onde ela vai sempre estar presente**.
- Terceiro motivo, a própria tag da função não existe, ou seja a imagem, botão formulario, ainda nem criou o evento como pode usar.

**Seguindo essa linha, isso não acontece mais**

> "funciona quando quer"

Coloquei exemplo, só para tentar ilustar o cenário

```
<div id="tag1">

</div>
<javascript>
    atualize(tag2); 
</javascript>
atualize tag no html acima, então chama ajax, quando ajax retorna não acha e não atualiza pois ela não existe 

<div id="tag1">
   <p id="tag2">
   </p>
</div>
Caso 3.
<javascript>
   atualize(tag2); 
</javascript>
script que arma o evento para chamar a função, não esta escutando, mesmo que a tag chamada tag2 exista.
```

Comment: Pode ser mais claro no segundo motivo, por favor? E como assim a tag da função não existe?

PS: Me desculpe se não possuo os mesmos entendimentos que você.

Comment: Coloquei exemplo, ve se ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Experimente colocar a verificação de sucesso ou erro dentro do próprio ajax, dessa maneira;

```
$.ajax({

    //códigos do ajax atual

    success : function(result){

        mudaPagina(result);   

    }
});
```

É interessante fazer os testes com o Inspecionar Elemento aberto, na aba "Rede" ou "Network", para poder ver as requisições que o navegador está fazendo ao vivo, bem como as respostas dessas requisições.